# How to fix audio file errors in python?

Tags: python, playsound, gtts

How to fix this error with code is:

```
def speak(text):
tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="vi")
filename = 'voice.mp3'
tts.save(filename)
playsound.playsound(filename)
os.remove(filename)
```

Its error is:

```
with open(str(savefile), "wb") as f:
PermissionError:[Errno 13] Permission denied:'voice.mp3'
```

I have tried many ways to no avail